# Why result starts diverging after certain number for Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm puzzled with results of computing sequence by different ways:

```
(defun fig-square-p (n)
  "Check if the given N is a perfect square number.

 A000290 in the OEIS"
  (check-type n (integer 0 *))
  (= (floor (sqrt n)) (ceiling (sqrt n))))

(defun fibonaccip (n)
  "Check if the given number N is a Fibonacci number."
  (check-type n (integer 0 *))
  (or (fig-square-p (+ (* 5 (expt n 2)) 4))
      (fig-square-p (- (* 5 (expt n 2)) 4))))

(defun fibonacci (n)
  "Compute N's Fibonacci number."
  (check-type n (integer 0 *))
  (loop :for f1 = 0 :then f2
     :and f2 = 1 :then (+ f1 f2)
     :repeat n :finally (return f1)))

(defun seq-fibonaccies (n)
  "Return sequence of Fibonacci numbers upto N."
  (check-type n (integer 0 *))
  (loop :for i :from 1 :upto n
     :collect (fib i)))
```

```
CL-USER> (loop :for i :from 0 :upto 7070 :when (fibonaccip i) :collect i)
(0 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 2889 3876 4181 5473
 6765 7070)
CL-USER> (seq-fibonaccies 21)
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946)
```

And when I increasing the limit of the loop the results start diverging much more.

```
~$ sbcl --version
SBCL 1.4.14-3.fc31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone else already mentioned, rounding errors accumulate quickly,
so you should stick with the integer arithmetics, using
[`isqrt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sqrt_.htm):

```
(defun squarep (n)
  "Check if the given N is a perfect square number.
https://oeis.org/A000290"
  (check-type n (integer 0 *))
  (let ((sqrt (isqrt n)))
    (= n (* sqrt sqrt))))
```

Also, you have a typo in `seq-fibonaccies` (`fib` instead of `fibonacci`).

Finally, `seq-fibonaccies` is *quadratic* in its argument, while it only
have to be *linear*.

Answer (score 0):

`fibonaccip` is going to give an estimated value because you don't have exact values for the square root of 5. As the value of *n* increases, the error will also incresase.